# jQuery Mobile Tab Navigation Delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, tabs

I have a tab control that uses Jquery mobile tab control. It works perfectly but the tab active status in `<li>` is delayed by 2 or 3 seconds i.e. when the user clicks the tab the content is loaded immediately but it takes 3 seconds time to highlight the tab header.

My code is below

```
<div data-role="tabs" id="tabsHistory" class="diaryMainTab">
<div data-role="navbar" class="arrow_Tabbox1 clsHistoryTab" id="divHistoryNavbar">
   <ul class="clsHistoryUl clsDynamicFontColor">
      <li id="recent_earned_active" class="clsHistoryLi1 clsHistoryAtag">
         <a href="#recent" data-ajax="false" 
            class="clsPyType clsHistoryTabAnch 
                   ui-btn-active clsTabPadRight diaryEvt">Recent</a>
      </li>
      <li class="clsHistoryLi3 clsHistoryAtag2">
         <a href="#overall" data-ajax="false" 
            class="clsPyType clsHistoryTabAnch clsTabPadRight upcomingEvt">Overall</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: is it same effect even if u remove your class from the <li> ?

Comment: Yes, I tried that before

Answer (score 0):

It could be the 300ms delay bug? [Heres a post](http://www.sitepoint.com/5-ways-prevent-300ms-click-delay-mobile-devices/) about how to get around this.